# How do I export setSearch?

Tags: reactjs

Want to be able to access this variable in other components. How do I export the setSearch variable? I have tried a number of syntax variations, and I can't seem to figure it out. As it stands the export setSearch is not working.

```
function SearchBar() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(search);
  };

  return (
    <BookSearch onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <SearchInput
        type="text"
        value={search}
        onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
      ></SearchInput>
      <SearchButton type="submit" value="Submit">
        Search
      </SearchButton>
    </BookSearch>
  );
}

export setSearch; 
export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: Did you try using the Context API or Redux? That's the way you should pass properties to other components that are not a child of your current component.

Comment: @luckongas thanks so much, this looks promising!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As referenced by @luckongas here's example of using `redux` with `context` api

```
import React, {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useReducer
} from "react";

const initialState = {
  'search': '',
};
const store = createContext(initialState);
const { Provider } = store;

const StateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'SET_SEARCH':
        return { ...state, 'search': action.payload };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }, initialState);

  return <Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>{children}</Provider>;
};

function DisplaySearch() {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(store);
  return <div>{state.search}</div>;
}

function SearchInput() {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(store);
  return (
    <input value={state.search} onChange={evt => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'SET_SEARCH',
          payload: evt.target.value,
        });
      }} />
  );  
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <StateProvider>
      <SearchInput />
      <DisplaySearch />
    </StateProvider>
  );
}
```

Here working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zrecog)

For more info you can check [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)